# tensorflow : How to compute L1 difference between the batch (matrix of size B X DIM) and vocabulary (matrix of size V X DIM)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensorflow objects as follows

```
batch = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3,2], name='batch')
vocab = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0], shape=[6,2], name='vocab')
```

batch has 3 vectors, each of 2 dimensions. vocab has 6 vectors, each of 2 dimensions.
I want to compute L1 difference between the every possible pair of vectors (generating 18 values).
e.g. L1 differences of [1,2] would be

```
|1-1|+|2-2|, |1-3|+|2-4|, |1-5|+|2-6|, |1-1|+|2-2|, |1-3|+|2-4|, |1-5|+|2-6|,
```

How can I do this with tensorflow functions ? The resulting matrix could be 6 X 3 (batch X vocab). Matrix multiplication seems to be the computation that will generate the expected order of the matrix. But is there a way to override the underlying operation of matrix multiplication ? (i.e. overriding the component-wise multiplication with absolute value of difference) ?

Comment: This could be a topic related to broadcasting (like in numpy). You can check out this: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/experimental/xla/broadcasting. I have not tried this yet (you will notice it's experimental).

Comment: Did you use `tf.matmul` instead of `*` (which does the Schur product as you mentioned)?

Comment: @drpng, Thanks. I tried it , but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this response is not useful to you anymore, but I recently came across to this example of [k-nearest neighbors](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/TensorFlow-Machine-Learning-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter%2005/nearest_neighbor.py) with L1 and L2 distance.
So, I guess, your problem can be solved as:

```
batch = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3,2], name='batch')
vocab = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0], shape=[6,2], name='vocab')
distance_L1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(vocab, tf.expand_dims(batch,1))), axis=2)
```

Good luck!